# Why are my preferences reset after restart with Mavericks?

Tags: finder, macos, preferences

My desktop wallpaper, the desktop icons - the file preview icon goes away, my default sound device, all get reset back to the default after a restart.

I removed the com.apple.desktop.plist from the Library folder, but it still reset.

How can I fix this?

Comment: Has it always been like this with Mavericks for you? Are you sure you are not on a "Guest" account?

Comment: I have noticed a couple of settings (Safari, for instance) being reset after reboot, since I upgraded to Mavericks. I wonder if it has to do with the dreaded cached preferences thing introduced in 10.9...

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried repairing the permissions on your home folder?  Sounds like the Finder is having trouble writing the necessary preference files.

Comment: i have, to no avail :(

Comment: You could try changing them by brute force:

    chown -R YOURusername /Users/YOURusername/; chgrp -R staff /Users/YOURusername/; chmod u+r+w-x,g+r-w-x,o+r-w-x /Users/YOURusername/

Comment: Is there a way to check the current permissions?

Comment: Yes, you can use the ls -al command to view detailed a permissions readout.